# Detect if AWS Server is behind a Load Balancer or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

Currently the same website is running under two different server configurations and under two different URLs.

- A farm of IIS servers sitting behind a load balancer
- A single IIS server with an elastic IP

For convenience it would be nice to have the same code running on all servers as it will simplify deployment procedures.

I know that I can do things like this:

`if (string.Equals(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"], "https"))`

This checks if the load balancer forwarded 'https' data. However, what I want to do is simply detect if a load balancer exists or not.

Essential I want to write: `if(LoadBalancerExists) { do this stuff }`

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Add a rule on the load balancer to add a custom http header? And then read it.

Comment: How do I add a custom http header?

Comment: Any reason you can't simply make this a configuration setting and set it in your deployment script?

Comment: Currently a deployment script is non-existent as I'm just testing at the moment, maybe that is the better way.

Comment: At startup, retrieve the instance ID of the current EC2 instance, then make an API call to describe the ELB and then see if your instance ID is registered with the ELB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if the load balancer does not exist `Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"] == null`.

If it does exist `Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"] == 'http' or 'https'`

Quick Solution: `if(Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"] == null) { do stuff }`

Updated Solution with added security since headers can be spoofed:

```
ClientIP = Request.UserHostAddress;
Subnet = <enter your aws CIDR subnet address>;    // e.g. 172.0.0.0
Mask = <enter your aws VPC address>;              // e.g. 255.255.0.0

// Verify header
if(Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"] == null) {
    // Verify that ClientIP i.e. the LoadBalancer's IP is inside of our subnet.
    if(IsAddressOnSubnet(ClientAddress, Subnet, Mask)) {
        // do some stuff
    }
}

protected bool IsAddressOnSubnet(IPAddress Address, IPAddress Subnet, IPAddress Mask)
{
    try
    {
        Byte[] addressOctets = Address.GetAddressBytes();
        Byte[] subnetOctets = Mask.GetAddressBytes();
        Byte[] networkOctets = Subnet.GetAddressBytes();

        return
            ((networkOctets[0] & subnetOctets[0]) == (addressOctets[0] & subnetOctets[0])) &&
            ((networkOctets[1] & subnetOctets[1]) == (addressOctets[1] & subnetOctets[1])) &&
            ((networkOctets[2] & subnetOctets[2]) == (addressOctets[2] & subnetOctets[2])) &&
            ((networkOctets[3] & subnetOctets[3]) == (addressOctets[3] & subnetOctets[3]));
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks to Michael-sqlbot for pointing out the security issue.

This [aws reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html) is useful.

Reference for detecting that ip address is on subnet [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0ecc0de-b45e-4ca4-8d57-fc9babd4c221/evaluate-if-ip-address-is-part-of-a-subnet?forum=netfxnetcom&prof=required#b6ef6ead-0918-45c6-9e88-7fc0177f0700) thanks to Спасибо! Прекрасное решение!.

Comment: Remembering that it is possible for these headers to be spoofed, a potentially more deterministic test would be whether the header is present *and* the connected client IP is inside the private IP address ranges assigned to the subnets of the ELB.  If both are true, it's from the ELB, if the IP test is false, it isn't, regardless of the presence of the header.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot How do I `test that the connected client IP is inside the private IP address ranges assigned to the subnets of the ELB`?

Comment: C# is not my specialty.  Perhaps something like `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot This is an external site and the client ip could be anything, or I do not understand what is meant by client ip.

Comment: The client IP should be a private IP from one of the ELB subnets if the request comes through the ELB, otherwise not.

Comment: The ways I know are: `Request.UserHostAddress` (non-load balancer) and `Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].ToString()` (with load balancer)

Comment: Okay, so if `Request.UserHostAddress` returns an address from one of the load balancer subnets, which you can determine with pattern matching, then you have a request that came through an ELB.